# Pull columns from derived table and sum them in one MySQL SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, derived-table

I need to pull column data from two tables, run calculations on the data with the result saved as an alias, and then sum those results into other alias' to display in a php table. I am trying to achieve this by creating a derived table within my SELECT statement but it doesn't work. I don't receive any errors but my table only displays the column headers.

CODE:

```
$sql = "SELECT x.company, x.stagestatus, x.shippeddate, SUM(x.totprice) as totalprice, SUM(x.sgtotquantity) as sgtotqty, SUM(x.sgtotalsqft) as sgtotsqft, SUM(x.avgsqftrev) as avgsqftrevenue, SUM(x.avgunitrev) as avgunitrevenue FROM (SELECT t1.company, t1.stagestatus, t1.shippeddate, t1.id, FORMAT(TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice), 2) AS totprice, t2.invoiceid, SUM(t2.quantity) AS sgtotqauntity, FORMAT(SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144, 2) AS sgtotalsqft, FORMAT((TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice)/(SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144)), 2) as avgsqftrev, FORMAT((TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) / SUM(t2.quantity)), 2) AS avgunitrev
  FROM invoices AS t1 INNER JOIN lineitems AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.invoiceid
  WHERE (t2.invoiceid = t1.id)
  GROUP BY t1.id) x
WHERE x.stagestatus='Complete'
GROUP BY x.company ASC";
```

This code breaks but when I use the smaller pieces individually, it works ok.

EX:

```
$sql="SELECT invoices.id, invoices.orderdate, invoices.stagestatus, FORMAT(TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM invoices.totalprice), 2) AS totalprice, clients.company, lineitems.invoiceid, SUM(lineitems.quantity) AS sgtotqty, FORMAT(SUM(lineitems.width * lineitems.height * lineitems.quantity ) /144, 2) AS sgtotsqft, FORMAT((TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM invoices.totalprice)/(SUM(lineitems.width * lineitems.height * lineitems.quantity ) /144)), 2) as avgsqftrevenue, FORMAT((TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM invoices.totalprice) / SUM(lineitems.quantity)), 2) AS avgunitrevenue
FROM clients
INNER JOIN invoices ON clients.id = invoices.clientid
INNER JOIN lineitems ON invoices.id = lineitems.invoiceid
WHERE (lineitems.invoiceid = invoices.id) AND invoices.orderdate BETWEEN '".$revenuefrom."' AND '".$revenueto."' AND invoices.stagestatus IN (". implode(',', array_map(function($item) {return '"' . $item . '"'; }, $revenue_check)) .")
GROUP BY invoices.id DESC";
```

This code works just fine and groups all data by invoices.id. However, the project needs were adjusted and now everything must group by invoices.company. When I simply try to group by invoices.company instead of invoices.id, my table completes but the values for each company row are very inaccurate, (aren't sum()ing right).

PHP CODE where table is built:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);


    echo "<table id='revenueReportA' align='center' class='report_DT'>
    <thead>
    <tr>

    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Total Revenue</th>
    <th>Total SQ FT</th>
    <th>AVG Revenue Per SQ FT</th>
    <th>Total Number of Units</th>
    <th>AVG Revenue Per Unit</th>
    </tr>
    </head>";


 if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

   // fetch associative array 
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  echo "<tbody>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" ."$". $row['totalprice'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['sgtotsqft'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;". "ft<sup>2</sup>". "</td>";
  echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgsqftrevenue'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['sgtotqty'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgunitrevenue'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</tbody>";
  } 

   echo "</table>";

echo "<BR>";
```

All help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: When you execute the first query what is the error?

Comment: Good grief. Don't store '$'. And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: lol My bad... Spelling error. When I call to SUM(x.sgtotalquantity), I spelled it as x.sgtotalqauntity. Upon fixing the error, my table displays the data, but its still significantly off. It's still as if the SELECT statement isn't able to find every invoice row to sum those values from the derived table...

Comment: Actually, just got it. Formatting issue. I Will post the changes.

Comment: @Strawberry Please provide an explanation about WHY '$' shouldn't be stored. Explanations are key when placing comments/answers...

Comment: Because it's contrary to the principals of normalisation.

Comment: @Strawberry Noted. Thank you for your explanation today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a spelling mistake and a formatting issue. By formatting the final data instead of formatting within the embedded SELECT statement, my table data was accurate.

Successful CODE:

```
$sql = "SELECT x.company, x.stagestatus, x.shippeddate, FORMAT(SUM(x.totprice), 2) as totalprice, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotquantity), 2) as sgtotqty, FORMAT(SUM(x.sgtotalsqft), 2) as sgtotsqft, FORMAT(SUM(x.avgsqftrev), 2) as avgsqftrevenue, FORMAT(SUM(x.avgunitrev), 2) as avgunitrevenue FROM (SELECT t1.company, t1.stagestatus, t1.shippeddate, t1.id, TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) AS totprice, t2.invoiceid, SUM(t2.quantity) AS sgtotquantity, SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144 AS sgtotalsqft, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice)/(SUM(t2.width * t2.height * t2.quantity ) /144)) as avgsqftrev, (TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM t1.totalprice) / SUM(t2.quantity)) AS avgunitrev
FROM invoices AS t1 INNER JOIN lineitems AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.invoiceid
WHERE (t2.invoiceid = t1.id)
GROUP BY t1.id) x
WHERE x.stagestatus='Complete'
GROUP BY x.company ASC";
```

Thank you!!!